# Jquery UI tabs preShow?

Tags: jquery, events, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jquery ui tabs. 
It has a couple of events like add, show, etc. I'd like an event that is triggered before the tab is added to the html, because I need to set width of the tab before it is added (for dynamic width purposes that I cant seem to do with CSS).

Any idea how I can make a pre-show event that is triggered before the tab is actually added?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the properties on your tab before it is added. DOM Elements can be wrapped in a jQuery object and manipulated before they are appended to the document.

Without specific code examples, its hard to know exactly what you are trying to achieve, or put it into context. Could you post some code?

Comment: Maybe I was a little unclear, but im using jquery ui tabs, which have events for show, add, remove, etc. But not preShow, which I could need.